# Is there any Jgit API by which we can read contents from particular file on GIT repo. without cloning all the data inside it

Tags: java, git, github, jgit

I have a requirement to read and fetch the data from a particular file on GIT Repo. This file data gets changed for every release so there are lots of branches from where I have to fetch those file data.

My issue is I don't want to clone the entire repo. Is it possible to clone that particular file only for every branch or remotely read the data without cloning anything?

Whatever I know there is no any Jgit API to clone any particular data file inside a folder, we have to clone the entire repo to read any data inside it.

Can anyone guide me on this?

Thanks,
Anshu

Answer (score 0):

Instead of jgit I would use the library from https://github.com/hub4j/github-api which allows to access and fetch data from github directly.

Comment: Appreciate your response, but my Git repo. is not on Github.